# store the BlobKey in the model

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am wondering about what the best way of saving a blobstore reference 
The documented way would be like so:

```
blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
```

or

```
ndb.BlobKeyProperty()
```

or

```
db.StringProperty()
```

Are there any disadvantages to save a text string of the key?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if you start using google cloud storage, it's blobkey will probably hold more information about its bucket/path etc but I haven't really used it so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty`
That works in my apps and if you need an image class that can hold several images you can use something like

```
class Image(db.Model):

    reference = db.ReferenceProperty(Article,
            collection_name='matched_images', verbose_name='Title')
    primary_image = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
```